# Determining tikz drawing style, depending on the values of two nested loop iterators

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-styles

So the question is a tikz one!

Assume that you are drawing things inside two nested foreach loops in tikz, and the iterator variables are `\x` and `\y`. What I'd like to obtain is to be able to specify a list of `(x,y)` pairs, s.t when drawing inside my two nested loops, I can apply one predefined style "A" if `(\x,\y)` matches a pair in the list, otherwise applies style "B".

Any ideas on how I can obtain this?

Simple example could be the following  code, which draws 16 lines on a sheet. I might want the condition that when `\x` is even, then it should use style "B" instead of style "A", but in all generality, I want to be able to specify the specific `(\x,\y)` pairs that will use style "B" rather than "A".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        A/.style={draw,color=red},
        B/.style={draw,color=blue}
    ]
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} {
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} {
            \draw[A] (2*\x,4*\y) -- (4*\y,3*\x);
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you introduce a simple red blue example? It doesn't have to be functional but complete in terms of copy/paste. It's great to play around with questions but setting them up with documentclass etc. is pretty dull.

Comment: As requested, I added an example. I hope this is what you mean by "red blue example" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update: using xstring

My original solution used `stringstrings` package which is *extremely* slow. Package `xstring` provides the same functionality, with a cleaner syntax, and it is much faster.

The following example (which uses `xstring`) takes 0.902s to compile in my box. The same example using `stringstrings` requires 16.575s!

This example is the same you posted in your question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
A/.style={draw,color=red},
B/.style={draw,color=blue}
]
\def\mylist{(0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} {
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} {
     \IfSubStr{\mylist}{(\x,\y)}{\def\mystyle{B}}{\def\mystyle{A}}
     \draw[\mystyle] (2*\x,4*\y) -- (4*\y,3*\x);
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

## Original answer:

An easy solution using `stringstrings` package (perhaps not the more adequate to deal with lists, but it's easy to use and does the work in this case):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
 a/.style = {fill=yellow!20, ultra thick},
 b/.style = {fill=black!20}
}

\def\mylist{(3,2) (2,1) (4,1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \foreach \y in {1,...,3} {
     \whereisword{\mylist}{(\x,\y)}
     \ifnum\theresult=0\def\mystyle{b}\else\def\mystyle{a}\fi
     \node[draw, circle, \mystyle] at (\x,\y) {\x,\y};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This is definately a solution! However, using this trick seems to slow compilation A LOT. It takes about 10-15 seconds just to compile this single tikz figure now, and I will be having several of those in my paper.

Can I optimize it in any way, or do you know a faster solution?

Comment: @MartinLauridsen Updated answer :-)

Comment: Thank you, that improved quite a bit! Great answer, kudos.